# return URL for non-paypal user

Tags: paypal

will a person that pays with their credit card (not associated with a PayPal account) go to the return URL below...if not where do they go?

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="something">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="900000000">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="mem" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="0">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="CP" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="10"/>

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="AD" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="0">

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.something.com/ppd.aspx?TransID=<%=request.querystring("IDUNNO")%>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.something.com/ppc.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="modify" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input type="image" src="images/btn_paynow.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="use PayPal!">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have a *reason* to think the behavior is different?

Comment: yeah ... usually if the user is a PayPal user ... the user is directed to the return page and the transaction gets logged in my db. For some reason these transactions are not logged.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Seems after the credit card transaction, the user just sits on thanks for your order screen. User has to click on the Return to your site link from there and that takes the user to the paypal autoreturn screen to take them back to the screen you want them to go. Odd workflow from Paypal.

Comment: Odd workflow from you, you mean. You shouldn't be relying on user actions to record transactions. You should be waiting for the *money* to arrive, and acting on that. There is no legal transaction until you have the money.